# How to write with a single node in MPI

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I want to implement some file io with the routines provided by MPI (in particular Open MPI).

Due to possible limitations of the environment, I wondered, if it is possible to limit the nodes, which are responsible for IO, so that all other nodes are required to perform a hidden `mpi_send` to this group of processes, to actually write the data. This would be nice in cases, where e.g. the master node is placed on a node with high-performance filesystem and the other nodes have only access to a low-performance filesystem, where the binaries are stored.

Actually, I already found some information, which might be helpful, but I couldn't find further information, how to actually implement these things:

**1:** There is an info key `MPI_IO` belonging to the communicator, which tells which ranks provide standard-conforming IO-routines. As this is listed as an environmental inquiry, I don't see, where I could modify this.

**2:** There is an info key `io_nodes_list` which seems to belong to file-related info-objects. Unfortunately, the possible values for this key are not documented and `Open MPI` doesn't seem to implement them in any way. Actually, I can't even get the filename from the info-object which is returned by `mpi_file_get_info`...

As a workaround, I could imagine two things: On the one hand, I could perform the IO with standard Fortran routines, or on the other hand, create a new communicator, which is responsible for IO. But in both cases, the processes, which are responsible for IO have to check for possible IO from the other processes to perform manual communication and file interaction.

Is there a nice and automatic way to restrict the IO to certain nodes? If yes, how could I implement this?

Comment: Note that `MPI_IO` belongs to the predefined attributes of the execution environment and as such is read-only. It is mostly there for historical and portability reasons. On modern cluster systems its value is always `MPI_ANY_SOURCE` since all CPUs are in one way or another connected to the I/O subsystem.

Answer (score 4):

You explicitly asked about OpenMPI, but there are two MPI-IO implementations in OpenMPI.  The old workhorse is ROMIO, the MPI-IO implementation shared among just about every MPI implementation.   OpenMPI also has OMPIO, but I don't know a whole lot about tuning that one.

Next, if you want things to happen automatically for you, you'll have to use collective i/o.  The independent I/O routines cannot send a message to anyone else -- they are independent and there's no way to know if the other side will be listening.

With those preliminaries out of the way...

You are asking about "i/o aggregaton".   There is a bit of information here in the context of another optimization called "deferred open" (and which OMPIO calls Lazy Open)

https://press3.mcs.anl.gov/romio/2003/08/05/deferred-open/

In short, you can definitely say "only these N processes should do I/O", and then the collective I/O library will exchange data and make sure that happens.  The optimization was developed some 15-odd years ago for just the situation you proposed: some nodes being better connected to storage than others (as was the case on the old ASCI Red machine, to give you a sense for how old this optimization is...)

I don't know where you got `io_nodes_list`.  You probably want to use the MPI-IO info keys `cb_config_list` and `cb_nodes`

So, you've got a cluster with master1, master2, master3, and compute1, compute2, compute3 (or whatever the hostnames actually are).  You can do something like this (in c, sorry.  I'm not proficient in Fortran):

```
MPI_Info info;
MPI_File fh;
MPI_Info_create(&info);
MPI_Info_set(info, "cb_config_list", "master1:1,master2:1,master3:1");
MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, filename, MPI_MODE_CREATE|MPI_MODE_WRONLY, info, &fh)
```

With these hints, MPI_File_write_all will aggregate all the I/O through the MPI processes on master1, master2, and master3.  ROMIO won't blow up your memory because it will chunk up the I/O into a smaller working set (specified with the "cb_buffer_size" hint: cranking this up, if you have the memory, is a good way to get better performance).

There is a ton of information about the hints you can set in the ROMIO users guide:
http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/romio/doc/users-guide/node6.html

Comment: Thanks for this very informative answer. I got the `io_nodes_list` from the `MPI-3` standard and I have no problem with the `C` language.  Though, I hoped for a non-collective possibility, to keep things unsynchronized.

Comment: Hah! I've been hacking on our MPI-IO implementation for nearly 13 years and I never knew about io_nodes_list.. .but there it is, in Section 13.2 under "Reserved File Hints".  ROMIO doesn't support the "filename" hint either...though that would be easy to implement.

Comment: You'll have to implement something on top of MPI-IO for a non-collective approach.  Some kind of distributed cache, say (Northwestern University did a bunch of work in this area in the 2008 time frame).  You could imagine RMA windows on the well-connected nodes, and hijacking MPI_Write to actually be MPI_Put... "the details are left to the reader"... and they are hairy details...

Comment: OMPIO in Open MPI 1.8 doesn't seem to be controllable in any way through the info argument. The info is simply stored so that it could be later retrieved using `MPI_FILE_GET_INFO`.